# Python: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute, which is untrue

Tags: python, pocketsphinx

**What I want to do:**

I want to import a python module (pocketsphinx) and use the output from the Decoder attribute. However when I try to use it, I'm informed that module attribute 'Decoder' doesn't exist.

```
decoder = Decoder(configSwitches)
```

It does exist, though, which is what makes it so strange.

**What I've done so far:**

When I pull up a python console and input `import pocketsphinx`, it imports without any issue. Running pocketsphinx.**file** returns:

`'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pocketsphinx-0.0.8-py2.7-linux-armv7l.egg/pocketsphinx/__init__.pyc'`

Looking in `'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pocketsphinx-0.0.8-py2.7-linux-armv7l.egg/pocketsphinx/__init__.py'`, I see: `from pocketsphinx import *` and that's it.

When I go back up to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pocketsphinx/pocketsphinx.py` and open it in a text editor, I see that pocketsphinx.py does indeed have a Decoder class with a healthy number of defined methods.

**My Ask:**

What other steps can I take to diagnose what's wrong with my use of the pocketsphinx module?

Here's the example code I was trying to run before really digging into the project:

```
import pocketsphinx


hmmd = r"/home/michael/Desktop/sphinxASR/pocketsphinx-5prealpha/model/en-us/en-us"
lmdir = r"/home/michael/Desktop/sphinxASR/pocketsphinx-5prealpha/model/en-us/en-us.lm.bin"
dictp = r"/home/michael/Desktop/sphinxASR/pocketsphinx-5prealpha/model/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict"
fileName = r'/home/michael/Desktop/sphinxASR/voice_message.wav'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    wavFile = open(fileName, "rb")

    speechRec = pocketsphinx.Decoder(hmm=hmmd, lm=lmdir, dictionary=dictp)

    wavFile.seek(44)

    speechRec.decode_raw(wavFile)

    result = speechRec.get_hyp()

    print(result)
```

Stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/27test/getHypTest.py", line 14, in <module>
    speechRec = pocketsphinx.Decoder(lm=lmdir, dictionary=dictp)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Decoder'
```

Comment: Did you try `from pocketsphinx import *`?

Comment: @Delgan yes, which is why I didn't use the command pocketsphinx.Decoder(configSwitches).

Comment: Ok. I do not know then, sorry.

Comment: @Delgan sorry if it felt like I was abrupt--I have tried that, but I didn't mention it in the post.

Comment: you should post the code that you are running that gives you the error.  otherwise we will have no idea what is going wrong. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example

Comment: Weird. I would have guessed you named your file `pocketsphinx.py`, but `pocketsphinx.__file__` seems to indicate the import system is finding the right file. Check `sys.version`; maybe you have a screwed-up Python installation with Python 3 trying to load Python 2 files. I don't know if Python 3 would load Python 2 `.pyc`s, though.

Comment: Can you post the complete error message, including the stack trace, and code that produces that error when run as the whole program?

Comment: @user2357112 sure, I'll put that up ASAP.

Comment: You say the module lives in `.../dist-packages/pocketsphinx/pocketsphinx.py`.  Perhaps you need to say `from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import Decoder`?

Comment: Are you sure about the path for the folder you found `pocketsphinx.py` in? It doesn't match the folder for `__init__.py`.

Comment: Yep. Here's the location output in the Files GUI: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pocketsphinx` That directory also has an __init__.py in it, also containing only `from pocketsphinx import *`

Comment: Sounds like you've got a messed-up pocketsphinx installation. You shouldn't have two copies of pocketsphinx.

Comment: @user2357112 The first directory was in the egg--should the file object have pointed to the actual module code?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the [pocketsphinx example code](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python/blob/master/example.py), it seems that your import should be:

```
from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
```

My first step diagnosing this issue would be to type the following, so that I can see what is being imported:

```
import pocketsphinx
dir(pocketsphinx)
```

Comment: The results of dir(pocketsphinx) are `['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']`

Comment: Also, the pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import returns `no module name pocketsphinx` which is just as bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

You should import Decoder from pocketsphinx.
Instead of

```
import pocketsphinx
```

try:

```
from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import Decoder
```

Comment: That just returns `no module called pocketsphinx`, which is even weirder.

Comment: It is weird. It probably suggests that you haven's installed pocketsphinx package completely. However, I am not sure about that.